# Webservice doesn't evaluate with multiple Arguments [REST API]

Tags: microsoft-excel, api, json

I am trying to fill a cell with a JSON response from the coindesk API using other cell that contain specific dates.

Here is a small screenshot of the formula:

[image]

This works only if I use the start argument and nothing else. In any other case it evaluates to #VALUE.

Do you know what I can do to solve this ?

Comment: Did you check Excel properly creates the URL?

Comment: When posting a question it is a **very** good idea to not just post a screenshot but also the actual formula and spreadsheet data. (Just like I've done in my answer.) This enables responders to easily copy and paste the data into a spreadsheet for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works only if I use the start argument and nothing else. In any other case it evaluates to #VALUE.

From the [coindesk API home page](https://www.coindesk.com/api/):

> We offer historical data from our Bitcoin Price Index through the following endpoint:
>
> ```
> https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json
> ```
>
> By default, this will return the previous 31 days' worth of data.

and

> **?start=<VALUE>&end=<VALUE>** Allows data to be returned for a specific date range. *Must be listed as a pair of start and end parameters*, with dates supplied in the YYYY-MM-DD format…

If you only supply the start parameter, it is ignored and the default 31 days is returned, *even if the supplied date is invalid!* If you supply both parameters, then the dates are checked and if either are invalid, an error is returned instead of the JSON data.

---

Now let's look at your spreadsheet:

```
Coin    Euro        Buy Date    Units       PPU/EUR     PPU/BTC     BTC2DATE    HelpDate    HelpString
DASH    EUR 400.00  2017-08-15  2.21717893  180.4094359             #VALUE!     2017-08-16  2017-08-16
DASH    EUR 400.00  2017-08-17  1.67020458  239.4916196             #VALUE!     2017-08-18  2017-08-18
```

Your BTC2DATE formula is:

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=[@[Buy Date]]&end=[HelpDate]")
```

What Daniel was suggesting in his comment to your question was to replace it with this:

```
="https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=[@[Buy Date]]&end=[HelpDate]"
```

to see the actual URL that is being passed to `WEBSERVICE()`. This turns out to be the literal string*:

https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=[@[BuyDate]]&end=[HelpDate]

And therein lies the problem. *Structured cell references do not work inside Excel strings!* They have to be concatenated just like normal cell references.

And so, finally, here is the solution:

```
=
WEBSERVICE(
  "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start="
  &TEXT([Buy Date],"yyyy-mm-dd")&"&end="
  &TEXT([HelpDate],"yyyy-mm-dd")
)
```

Note that, at least for Excel 2007, the dates need to be converted. Using just the raw cell references pulls in the underlying numeric values instead.

---

*<sub>Except for a space character in "Buy Date" that's impossible to keep *and* have a working hyperlink.</sub>